# mod_rewrite equivalent for IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite

Is there a mod_rewrite equivalent for IIS 7.0 that's

a) more or less complete

b) suitable for a production environment, i.e. battle-tested/dependable/secure

Do you have an experience-based recommendation?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check out the [URL Rewrite Module for IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) created by Microsoft

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Comment: http://varunpant.com/posts/mod-proxy-equivalent-in-iis-using-arr-and-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 4):

If you have $99.00 to spare you may want to take a look at http://www.isapirewrite.com/

[Excerpt from thier website]

**Product overview**

ISAPI_Rewrite is a powerful URL manipulation engine based on regular expressions. It acts mostly like Apache's mod_Rewrite, but is designed specifically for Microsoft's Internet Information Server (IIS). ISAPI_Rewrite is an ISAPI filter written in pure C/C++ so it is extremely fast. ISAPI_Rewrite gives you the freedom to go beyond the standard URL schemes and develop your own scheme.

[Example of use] available at http://www.helicontech.com/articles/provocative_SEF_URLs.htm

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at URLRewriter. Used it in production once without problems. But don't rely on that as the only quality check:

http://www.codeplex.com/urlrewriter

*(It's free and has a Microsoft Public License)*

> Managed Fusion URL Rewriter is a powerful URL manipulation engine based on the Apache mod_rewrite extension. It is designed, from the ground up to bring all the features of Apache mod_rewrite to IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0. Managed Fusion Url Rewriter works with ASP.NET on Microsoft's Internet Information Server (IIS) 6.0 and Mono XPS Server and is fully supported, for all languages, in IIS 7.0, including ASP.NET and PHP. Managed Fusion Url Rewriter gives you the freedom to go beyond the standard URL schemes and develop your own scheme.

Answer (score 2):

[IIRF](http://IIRF.codeplex.com)

- works with IIS5, 6 or 7.
- Free
- open source
- well maintained
- Free
- supports regular expression pattern matching
- uses .htaccess syntax
- RewriteRule
- RedirectRule
- RewriteHeader
- RewriteCond
- Free
- use separate config file for each IIS application or site
- rule changes are loaded automatically
- ProxyPass
- Did I mention it is Free?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A pefect alternative to Apache mod_rewrite and other Apache modules on IIS7 is [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/). The syntax is 99% Apache compatible.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite was designed for IIS 7.0 and features great performance and administration UI.

Answer (score 1):

[IIS mod-rewrite](http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html) is the best option I know, but it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

[ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) is suitable for IIS 5 or 6. There's a Lite version available for free, or you can pay for the full version to get more features, such as proxying capabilities. It's been a while since I've used it, but it worked fine at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Helicon Ape since jumped off from Apache and moved to IIS. It's syntax compatible with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You can read my article on how to use **Managed Fusion URL Rewriter** here:

http://carlos.mendible.com/2010/02/runnig-apache-behind-iis-server-net.html

Hope it helps.