# How can you get mod_rewrite compatible redirects to work with IIS/PHP?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, cakephp, iis-7

I'd like to be able to get some websites currently hosted in linux moved across to Windows-based hosting where we already have a reasonable number of sites hosted (not looking to switch to Apache since majority of sites are relying upon IIS), and have tried a few different mod_rewrite variants for IIS but not had any success getting any configured to work correctly. A couple of sites I need this to work for are based on the CakePHP framework to give an example. Any help/suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

John Sheehan posted:

> Check out the [URL Rewrite Module for
> IIS 7](http://iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1691) created by Microsoft

[mod_rewrite equivalent for IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857/mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-iis-7-0)

Comment: I would also add that it includes the ability to import the mod_rewrite rules to its own format (XML based/web.config).

Answer (score 0):

I've had quite a bit of success with [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) in the past.  It uses very similar rules to mod_rewrite.