# How create an XML feed using php and mysql

Tags: php, xml

I created a rss feed for my site and the url looks like this: http://abcde.com/rss/rss.php

I want an url like this: http://abcde.com/rss/rss.xml

How to do this, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What web server are you using? Most people use a rewrite rule in Apache

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess rules?

If you want *all* .xml files to point to php files, use these.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /rss

RewriteRule  ^(.*).xml$ $1.php [R=301]
```

This should also work:

```
RedirectMatch perm ^/rss/(.+)\.xml$ http://yoursite.com/rss/$1.php
```

Otherwise, use the code Jason McCreary suggested:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /rss

RewriteRule  ^rss.xml$ rss.php [L]
```

Which will only rewrite rss.xml to rss.php.

Comment: I'm assuming apache, I don't know the solution on other web servers. Apparently this is the solution on IIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857/mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-iis-7-0

Comment: This is a bit aggressive. It's better to be specific, i.e. `^rss.xml$ rss.php [L]` Otherwise, all `.xml` requests will be redirected to `.php`

Comment: Great point @Jason. When I did something similar, that was the desired behavior but I didn't consider the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to generate a static xml file via php and give access to this file.

Invoking php script that reads back-end database every time to generate rss feed, especially when there are many users, may affect on your server performance.

Generate a static xml file and update it every time when you update your web-site.

And provide link to this static xml file.