# Is it possible to change the url of a static .html without changing the name of the file?

Tags: html

I would like to know if there is a way to change the url of a `.html` file without changing the name of the file. Eg. if I have a website with a page called `1.html`, is there a way to make it appear as `mypagename.html` to visitors and crawlers?

Comment: I think you can tell Apache eg to serve files under particular URLs. Don't know enough about it to write a proper answer though ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called URL-rewriting. URL-rewriting implementation differs between different platforms. So, you have to state your server application (e.g. Apache, IIS etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
Now I know that it would work with eg "RewriteRule   ^mypagename.html$   1.html". One question still though. I plan to do this with a lot of pages. Do you think there is a maximum of pages for this kind of rewriting or doesn't it use too much server resources? Eg. 1.000.000 rewrites or more.


Thanks again.

Comment: You can use regular expression to translate input with a pattern. Actually you're using it even in your example. ^page.html$ is a valid regular expression. You can use something like ^page/(\d+)-(\w+).html$ and you can translate that into "156/hotnews.html" into "page156.html" with that regular expression (e.g. page$1.html rewrite rule). Please a have look at regular expression for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on *nix, it may be easiest to just use a link (soft may require a configuration change, hard will require you to remember that both names refer to the same file).

Note on enabling soft links: https://serverfault.com/questions/244592/followsymlinks-on-apache-why-is-it-a-security-risk

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML5 History API to push a new, possibly fake, address. I wouldn't suggest it tough.

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, but your host must provide URL rewriting. If you're on a Apache server look for `.htaccess` capabilities and `mod_rewrite`'s `RewriteRule` directive

Comment: I've removed Linux from your answer, mod_rewrite plays fine (and it's the same) on every platform.

Comment: Oh well, let's also **[remove Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857/mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-iis-7-0)**, as a requirement, then, won't we? :)