# How is this ASPX site constructed?

Tags: asp.net

How is this ASPX site constructed?

http://www.greatschools.org/california/plymouth/14685-County-Community-School/

I am building a similar site, but also a ASPX.NET noob.

I realize they have a MDB database, but how are hyperlinks from one page directed to such a SEO friendly URL?

What ASPX function(s) or tools should I be employing?

Any links to resources or tutorials very much welcome.

Comment: Not an ASP.NET site.  check the HTTP headers, if it were ASP.NET the server would be IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heart of your question has to do with getting those SEO friendly URLs. That is accomplished using URL Rewriting, or some variant.

With Microsoft products, you can solve this at the IIS level, or at the ASP.NET level.

For the IIS level, there is already a Q&A that answers far better than I can here: [mod_rewrite equivalent for IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857/mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-iis-7-0)

For the ASP.NET level, check out [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). You might be interested in learning more about, and doing tutorials for, [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). (Clean URLs are very inherent to its architecture.)

I do also want to clarify something. That site (greatschools.org) is probably not driven by Microsoft products:

- There aren't any of the telltale signs in the source code for ASP.NET, such as viewstate or inclusion of any Microsoft JavaScript libraries.
- The server responds that it is Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_perl/1.31 mod_ssl/2.8.31, OpenSSL/0.9.8e mod_jk/1.2.28

Those could certainly be twisted by a developer to mislead people as to the identity of the server, but that seems unlikely to me.

Comment: something else to consider is the number of techniques they use to construct the website. too many to list them here, but needless to say, this wasn't designed by noobs.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for assuming it was ASPX. So I use this as a better example: http://www.schooldigger.com/go/WA/district/01260/search.aspx   How do I learn to create aspx page templates to display database info from a search box on another page (search by zip code, then display page with content for that zipcode).

Comment: I'd make another question for that, or... completely rewrite your original question. Your initial question was about SEO friendly URLs in ASP.NET.