# Allowing username extensions for your website (ie, http://example.com/someusername)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a social networking site. Something that I would like to do is have the user's username come after my websites name... like example.com/myusername. I know I could do something using $_GET variables where it would look like example.com/?u=myusername, but we think that having just the username after after the domain would look cleaner and be easier for users to navigate.

Thanks in advance,

JS

Comment: What web server? There are many examples available.

Comment: I suggest you use `example.com/user/username` - that way there are less restrictions on usernames, because users may want to have names like `404`, `index.html`, etc.

Comment: right now, im using a single IIS server... today or tomorrow i'll be switching to a distibuted site using apache httpd with php5 on ubuntu server 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a rewrite rule to direct all non-existent requests to your `index.php` (or really whatever script you want to use). Then just inspect the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and pull out the username.

Here's a basic set of rewrite rules (for apache):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And in your case:

```
$requestParts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$username = $requestParts[0];
```

That would allow you to also use: `example.com/username/posts/newest`, and pull out the various 'parts'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache then look for mod_rewrite.
If you are using IIS then read here: [mod_rewrite equivalent for IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857/mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-iis-7-0).

Use either to parse the calling URL and build vars for your page.