# How to enable mod_rewrite on windows server 2003

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How can I enable mod_rewrite on Windows Server 2003?
PHP is installed as a service (probably from installer) in c:\php directory.

Search engine can not find the httpd.conf file, 
also there is no c:\program files\apache directory.

I have IIS6.

Comment: are you sure Apache is install maybe you install IIS? cheek window service for Apache php cann't install as service

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857/mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-iis-7-0

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur maybe I did not install it.
But in fact, it can be detected by the fact the IIS to restart php I need to restart IIS
look here http://i.imgur.com/m1Z9kgz.jpg

Comment: if you want to use Apache and  mod_rewrite You must remove IIS from Server manager Roles or disable it and install Apache instead.